# What's the best way to provide animation grabs, e.g. when asking questions about coreanimation?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

This is a little meta, but I'd like to ask a question related to coreanimation on the iphone, and I think it would really benefit from some kind of movie attachment / link to show what the code does. Probably I'm not the only one who'd like to do this.

My question is, what's the best way to illustrate an animation, grab it from the device or simulator, and attach it to a SO question?

This is basically the equivalent of a screenshot, but it needs to show the movement. Would a sequence of screen grabs be enough? Or some kind of mov file? And what tools exist to capture that with the minimum of pain.

Answer (score 2):

Screenshots should be good enough (particularly if you annotate the movement direction of an animating object).  If you wish to grab movies, I highly recommend running the application in the simulator and using [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) to capture and edit your video.  Unfortunately, that may not give a true representation of the animation frame rate you see on an actual device.

Comment: I agree with Brad. Just use the simulator to capture a movie. You can use iShowU HD (http://store.shinywhitebox.com/store/shop.php ) instead of ScreenFlow if your budget is tight. It works very well too. As far as sharing it on SO, you can use a hosting service like YouTube or Vimeo and then paste the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a set of screen-shots are enough to attach to a SO question - otherwise I think you would need to shot a video with another device.